# How to correct delete catalina.out?

Tags: java, tomcat, size, delete-file, catalina.out

I couldn't restart Tomcat webserver. But catalina.out get very big. 
I have tried delete on test server and created new empty. But Tomcat doesn't write anymore in new catalina.out. How correct delete/create empty new one ?

Comment: you don't need to create one. it will be automatically created. perhaps you've created with `root` or another user which leads tomcat to not open it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are using Gnu/Linux or Mac OS X, you can just do:

```
echo "" > catalina.out
```

or even shorter:

```
> catalina.out
```

Comment: as @Mustafa Genç said, you might have created the file as `root`? if so, delete it, don't recreate it, let tomcat create it automatically.

Comment: Important thing - don't delete never!!! Because program keeps file descriptor. File should be truncated as is suggested in this answer

Answer (score 15):

for me

```
echo "" > catalina.out
```

or

```
sudo echo "" > catalina.out
```

didn't work, as the file was created with root/other user privilege

```
sudo truncate -s 0 catalina.out
```

worked for me. here -s is for size and I am setting the file size to 0

Answer (score 1):

In base Tomcat installs, `catalina.out` is usually the result of stdout/stderr redirections via the Tomcat launcher script.

If you run Tomcat on a Unix system, and if you delete the file while Tomcat is running, the problem is that the process will still have a descriptor open to that file and continue to write on it. The solution is therefore to use a program dedicated to handling such cases. For instance, logrotate (which is standard in pretty much all Linux distributions).

Answer (score 0):

When `tomcat` server is used, it is pretty normal that the disk usage increases as logs accumulate in the `catalina.out` file.

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts and writes to it. But in your case, since `catalina.out` was deleted while `tomcat` was running it is holding up the file reference and writing to the deleted file. You can get rid of this by restarting the `tomcat` server.

Actually you can clear the log of `catalina.out` file without stopping tomcat with the command below.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

To keep `catalina.out` smaller and backup older logs, either one of the following ways can be used:

1. You could use the above `Linux` command and add it to a `CronScheduler`
   to run daily/ weekly/ monthly or yearly as preferred.
2. Use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
   in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
   Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
   file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
   info on this.